# Reliably identify File Objects in JavaScript, like Hash or so

Tags: javascript, file, hash

For uploading files in the Webbrowser, I implemented a file queue.
This is simply an Array that holds the file objects.

```
var filecache = new Array();
$(".fileinput").on("change", function (e) {
    $.each(e.target.files, function (k, file) {
        filecache.push(file);
    });
});
```

Using this array, I need to have a function to remove specific files from that Array.

A File Object in JavaScript only contains a few properties: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File

So when I want to remove a specific file from that FileObject-Aray, these are the properties I could use. But reliably is none of them. Two or more files in that Array can have the same name, so the name property will not be my choice.

I wonder if I could somehow create a Hash, a unique Key or something alike, out of the properties I have, to identify a specific file.
Is there a way to solve this problem? I know, Hashes are painful in JavaScript, but maybe someone knows another practical way.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `id` property to file object and then put it to array.

`id` generation might be as trivial as function with state which returns incremented value or you can go even further and compute MD5 or CRC from the Blob.